How were Gambit's accent and the related jokes handled in the dubbed versions of Deadpool & Wolverine?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Gambit speaks with his signature Cajun accent, which becomes a recurring source of humor. Deadpool jabs at Gambit for being difficult to understand. After Gambit introduces himself, Deadpool quips, "It's been a while since I've seen Sling Blade. Hit me again," referencing the similarly unique accent of the protagonist in that film. Later, he ribs Gambit by asking, "Who is your dialect coach? The Minions?"
This raises an interesting question about how Gambit's distinctive accent was handled in dubbed versions of the film. Given that Cajun English is heavily influenced by French, how did other languages approach this linguistic challenge? Did they simply add a French accent to their dubs, or did they find more creative solutions?
The French dub, in particular, presents an intriguing case. How did they tackle the portrayal of an accent that's already partially based on their language?
It's worth noting that in other instances of dubbing Deadpool & Wolverine, jokes were modified to suit the specific language rather than being directly translated. For example, in the case of jokes about a particular character's identity, the dubbing incorporated clever references related to the voice actors' history in their respective languages: What jokes were made in the dubbed versions of Deadpool & Wolverine regarding this character's identity?
How exactly was Gambit's accent represented in various dubs, and how were the accent-related jokes adapted to maintain their humor across different languages?
